# CALayer animation reverts

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation

I have been trying to do `CALayer` animation. But after animation it reverts back.I found a few solutions like `removedOnCompleteion  = YES` and `fill mode = kCAFillModesForwards` but none is helping me. here is the code. Need a little help fellows thx.

```
  void(^ myblock)(NSDictionary *) = ^(NSDictionary *dict){

        NSMutableArray *arrOfPt=       [dict objectForKey:@"Path"];

        CGPoint p1 = [[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];

        CGPoint cp1 = [[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];

//        CGPoint cp1 = [[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint cp2 = [[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:2] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint p2 = [[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:3] CGPointValue];

        NSMutableArray *arrayTime =  [dict objectForKey:@"Time"];
        CGFloat time = [[arrayTime objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        pointerLayer.opacity = 1;
//        NSArray *oneObjPt = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[arrOfPt objectAtIndex:0],[arrOfPt lastObject],nil];
        //         NSArray *oneObjTime = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[arrayTime objectAtIndex:0],[arrayTime lastObject],nil];
//        NSArray *oneObjTime = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],nil];
        CAKeyframeAnimation *keyFrameAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

//        [keyFrameAnimation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationPaced];
        keyFrameAnimation.duration = 1;
        keyFrameAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [keyFrameAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

        CGMutablePathRef fpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPathMoveToPoint(fpath, NULL, p1.x, p1.y);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(fpath, NULL, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        keyFrameAnimation.path = fpath;

        [pointerLayer addAnimation:keyFrameAnimation forKey:@"pos"];
        CGPoint newLoc = pointerLayer.position;// this is just to verify the layer's location
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a few solutions like removedOnCompleteion = YES and fill mode = kCAFillModesForwards

Those are not solutions.

> CGPoint newLoc = pointerLayer.position;

That won't do any good; adding an animation does not actually change the position. The animation happens *later*.

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but it might help you to read my explanation of Core Animation. Animation is just an illusion; it's a game played with the "presentation layer". It is up to *you* to move the *real* layer to where it is going to be after the animation *and* to add the animation that will appear to make it move there.

I provide a formulaic approach for making sure that your Core Animation works to get you where you want to go:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to recreate this - granted I used some test data:

```
CGPoint cp1 = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGPoint cp2 = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGPoint cp3 = CGPointMake(85, 150);
CGPoint cp4 = CGPointMake(50, 50);
CGFloat time = 2.0f;
CAKeyframeAnimation *keyFrameAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
keyFrameAnimation.duration = time;
keyFrameAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[keyFrameAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

CGMutablePathRef fpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(fpath, NULL, cp1.x, cp1.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(fpath, NULL, cp2.x, cp2.y, cp3.x, cp3.y, cp4.x, cp4.y);
keyFrameAnimation.path = fpath;
[testView.layer addAnimation:keyFrameAnimation forKey:@"pos"];
CFRelease(fpath);
```

which outputs:

http://glassofcocoa.com/code/AnimationTest.mp4

Possibly one of your points in the array might be the starting position?